# I have a zoom bar and a legend. I want to right align the items to each other as well as when the page moves

Tags: css, arcgis-js-api

I want the right side of the zoom bar aligned with the right side of the legend. I've tried text-align: right and it did not work.

```
.esri-ui-top-left.esri-ui-corner{
  text-align: right;
  left:97%;
 }

 .esri-ui-bottom-left.esri-ui-corner{
  text-align: right;
  left:97%;
 }
```

I have it like this

[image]

How can i make it so that it looks like this

[image]

Comment: could you please provide a minimal reproducible example which shows your own efforts as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of overriding CSS classes, use the JavaScript methods provided by the API for positioning default components, widgets or custom HTML elements:

```
// Reposition widget
view.ui.move("zoom", "top-right");

// Add component (can be a Widget or HTMLElement)
var component = new BasemapGallery({
  view: view
});
view.ui.add(component, {position: "top-right"});
```

For a running example, see the following CodePen: https://codepen.io/arnofiva/pen/ff5f29c0037ac5ee98d79685a126ee84

For more information, have a look at the following resources:

- [DefaultUI](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-ui-DefaultUI.html)
- [Create Custom Widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/widgets-custom-widget/index.html)

Comment: Thank you this made it a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ugly solution. Basically you can rap them in a div and set alignment and margins accordingly.

```
<style>
.small {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: right;
 }

.large {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 50px;
 }

 .container {
   float: right;
   margin-right: 50px;
 }
</style>


<div class="container">
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="large"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f2wxc1dv/